# Find google place ID string on marker button click

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to get place Id when user clicks on marker button of map.

Here is my code :

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        // marker.showInfoWindow();
        marker.getId();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityDetails.class));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here marker.getId() shows a different value like "m13". I want google place Id like `ChIJAQAAAKTPXzkRCOuJI4ZUtN4` when user clicks on marker button on map.

Comment: then use some dictionary container to store Marker ID with coresponded place id before adding marker to the map ... then in on marker click get this value from dictionary based on marker id

Answer (score 0):

To get a place id you have to get correct place name first . and you are getting a latlng from the map click listener so we have to do following steps -

1. get latlng from map

   ```
   @Override
       public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
   ......
   ```

   the latlng is the object we are going to use for further operation.
2. Get address from the latlng by reverse geo-coding

   ```
   Geocoder geocoder;
   List<Address> addresses = null;
               geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
   try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
   ```
3. Now you pass these address into the following url and you get your placed id in json format .

   ```
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=THE_ADDRESS_YOU_WANT_TO_GIVE&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY
   ```

These are the complete steps you need to do. use this in your logic as you need. don't forget to handle the exceptions . this is most important in google maps .

try the passing address to url some times , this might be a problem for you.